# Neo4j trouble loading node file

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to load a file to Neo4j with Id, Type, Artist, netWorth as headers to create a node.

This is the command I am giving:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/Neo4jFiles/VerticesArtistsById.csv" AS csvLine
    CREATE (p:Artist { id: toInteger(csvLine.Id), name: csvLine.Artist, netWorth: csvLine.netWorth})
```

and I am getting `Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed` - `Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/ComputerName/Desktop/neo4j/import/Neo4jFiles/VerticesArtistsById.csv`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a security measure, neo4j assumes import files reside in the [import directory](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/configuration/file-locations/). The location of that directory can be [configured](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.directories.import).